# Eventbrite custom ticket pdf

Tags: eventbrite

Is it possible to use event_list_attendees to get the list of attendees and their specific information for the event in order to place it onto my own custom designed ticket graphic/PDF?

For instance, I want to create my own stand alone website that links to my event, have users register/purchase tickets, then from my website via the API, I would send the user a custom email as well as a custom designed ticket specific to my event. On the ticket itself I would want to pull the attendee name and number of tickets ordered, as well as the barcode and the event information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is totally possible. See the page on the [Eventbrite API - event_list_attendees](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_list_attendees/)

It should give you all the information you need.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested by Pygmento custom emails & tickets : https://www.pygmento.com/en/blog/eventbrite-custom-tickets-pdf/.

You can use the service customize the confirmation email and pdf ticket using any variable from Eventbrite : given name, surname, ticket class, barcode, or even the user-defined checkout fields.